# TCP connection not getting connected stuck i

Tags: service, connection, tcpclient, handshake, reboot

We have client and server connection setup

.Every day a service (on client side)gets restarted at 7am and connects to server via tcp at 7.30am because the server service starts at 7.30.But in intervals of 30 days the TCP connection fails.
But when I reboot the server and reboot is successful the client gets connected automatically.How can resolve this issue without rebooting the server.

When the connection does not established the TCP connection is in syn send state.

Comment: Iam rebooting the client machine